# How to have Movie Clips in Array Stack on top of each other?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, hittest

Hey Everyone so been at this for awhile now. So basically I am creating a game where objects fall down from top of the stage and once the player catches one object, I want other objects to be able to stack on top of the first object and keep going and going. Like you are stacking blocks on top of each other or something.

I have an Array where I hold the Movie clip that falls from the top of the stage every other interval of seconds. The movie clip is called `acorn` and here is how I have it setup to where the array of acorns are on the stage falling down:

```
    private function addAcorn():void 
    {
        TweenLite.delayedCall(acornNumber, addAcorn);
        var newAcorn = new mcAcorn;
        addChild(newAcorn);
        aAcornArray.push(newAcorn);
    }
```

in my Enter Frame Event Listener I have my `checkAcornHitSquirrel();`

and here is how I setup the function:

```
private function checkAcornHitSquirrel():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aAcornArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentAcorn:mcAcorn = aAcornArray[i];


            if (currentAcorn.hitTestObject(squirrel))
            {
                //Have Current Acorn Stack on Squirrel mouth and have mouth expand
                acorn = currentAcorn;
                currentAcorn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, trackAcorn);

                //aAcornArray.splice(i, 1);
                trace("SQUIRREL_ACORN_HIT_TEST");
            }

        }
    }
```

I have the Enter Frame event `trackAcorn` so when the player moves the acorns move with the player. Here is that function:

```
    private function trackAcorn(e:Event):void 
    {
        acorn.x = squirrel.x;
        acorn.y = squirrel.y - 50;
    }
```

So my main Idea to accomplish this would be to have a double for loop instead of the 1 for loop. But not sure if that would be the best method or how to really accomplish it. Please if you understand what I am trying to do and can help I would really appreciate it.

This is what I tried but only two acorns stack on each other the others pass thorough :/

```
private function checkAcornHitSquirrel():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aAcornArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentAcorn:mcAcorn = aAcornArray[i];

              for (var j:int = 0; j < aAcornArray.length; j++)
              {
                var stackAcorn:mcAcorn = aAcornArray[j];

                if (currentAcorn.hitTestObject(squirrel))
                {
                    //Have Current Acorn Stack on Squirrel mouth and have mouth expand
                    currentAcorn.x = squirrel.x;
                    currentAcorn.y = squirrel.y;
                    currentAcorn.stopAcorn();
                    //aAcornArray.splice(i, 1);
                    trace("SQUIRREL_ACORN_HIT_TEST");
                }

                if (currentAcorn.hitTestObject(stackAcorn) && currentAcorn.hitTestObject(squirrel) )
                {
                    stackAcorn.x = currentAcorn.x;
                    stackAcorn.y = currentAcorn.y - 30;
                }
              }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How could you stack in squirrels mouth so many acorn?

Comment: Haha. If there is a will there is a way.

Comment: So many beginners fail to understand how important and useful DisplayObjectContainer are. Create a simple Sprite, add it to your squirel then simply add your acorn to that sprite. No need for enterframe, no need for calculation or loop.

Comment: So I can use a DisplayObjectContainer in replace for all that? Everything would still work fine such as the acorns falling and stacking on top of each other if the user catches them? I would have no idea where to start havent worked with DisplayObjectContainers but I will definitely take a look into it. Thanks BotMaster

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the reference to `acorn` in `trackAcorn`. This variable no longer references the same acorn that it did when you added the eventListener, because it gets changed in every iteration of your for loop.

You could have a separate for loop iterating through all the acorns attached to the squirrel. You will just need separate lists for attached and unattached acorns. I guess this is what you mean by "double for loop"

You could also create a new Acorn class containing a reference to the MovieClip and logic for moving it. This would be more object oriented and make it more obvious which acorn is being moved where.

Comment: Interesting. So you think separate for loops would do the trick and not One Double for loop? Thanks for the information Ill try to set that up today.

Comment: If you need acorns to interact with each other then you will need a nested for loop. For each acorn, iterate through all the others and check for collision.
If acorns should only interact with the squirrel, then a single loop for collision checking, and either a separate loop to have them follow the squirrel or use addChild function on DisplayObjectContainer as suggested by BotMaster.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying now. Yeah I am only looking for one acorn to collision detection with the squirrel. After that I need the acorns to collision detect with each other and stack on top of each other. I will definitely try my best right now. One more question am I doing it right I updated my question on the bottom I show the nested for loop. Not sure if that is the correct way to iterate through all the acorns efficiently.